# Shiny - How to remember user input after click on refresh?

Tags: r, shiny

I've this Shiny app that ask an input from the user.
how can I hold the user input also after refresh the page?
for example - if the user write "hello" I'll see his input.
I want still see his last input even if he clicks on refresh

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary"),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A native shiny approach is "live" bookmarking - please see `?updateQueryString`

```
library(shiny)

ui = function(req) {
  fluidPage(
    textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary"),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
}

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    # Trigger this observer every time an input changes
    reactiveValuesToList(input)
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  onBookmarked(function(url) {
    updateQueryString(url)
  })
  output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Another approach would be to use use shiny's `onSessionEnded` callback to save the current state of the inputs e.g. via `save()` and `load()` them on session start - or using library([shinyStore](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyStore)) to save the inputs in the client browser's [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
# install.packages("devtools")
# library(devtools)
# install_github("trestletech/shinyStore")

library(shiny)
library(shinyStore)

ui <- fluidPage(
  initStore("store", "myUniqueNamespace"),
  textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary"),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$store$caption, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "caption")
    updateTextInput(session, "caption", value = input$store$caption)
  })
  
  observe({
    updateStore(session, "caption", input$caption)
  })
  
  output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: TY, I tri to use the first solution.

Comment: Say a user adds some inputs using the second method to save data in the browser's local storage. Now let's say another user opens the app on their computer, will that user be able to see the previous inputs added to the dataframe?

Comment: No - the storage is local (depending on the browser) and also the restoring process depends on the session.

Comment: So it's local in case of Chrome?

Comment: Each browser has its own localStorage just try it with the above app.