# How to separate shiny app to two files: UI and SERVER

Tags: r, shiny

I've this app:

```
library(shiny)

ui = function(req) {
  fluidPage(
    textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary"),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
}

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    # Trigger this observer every time an input changes
    reactiveValuesToList(input)
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  onBookmarked(function(url) {
    updateQueryString(url)
  })
  output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

I want to separate it to two files: ui.r and server.r
I tried to do it:

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
function(req) {
  fluidPage(
    textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary"),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
}
```

server.r

```
 function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    # Trigger this observer every time an input changes
    reactiveValuesToList(input)
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  onBookmarked(function(url) {
    updateQueryString(url)
  })
  output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })
}
```

but it is not running well.
I guess it because the missing row: shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")

any help will be wellcome

Comment: @YBS TY, but it doesn't work well. It is not remember my choice in the text input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can put `enableBookmarking("url")` in `global.R` to make [(live) bookmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715897/shiny-how-to-remember-user-input-after-click-on-refresh/72716172#72716172) work in a multi file app:

**global.R**

```
library(shiny)
enableBookmarking("url")
```

**ui.R**

```
ui = function(req) {
  fluidPage(
    textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary"),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
}
```

**server.R**

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    # Trigger this observer every time an input changes
    reactiveValuesToList(input)
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  onBookmarked(function(url) {
    updateQueryString(url)
  })
  output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })
}
```