# R Shiny DT preserve updated table to show it when app is reopened

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny app that allows the user to enter their project details to the database. This is achieved by clicking the `Add Project Details Button` that adds an empty row to the table. Now the next step is:

- The app should save (via a save button) the updated table so that the next time the app is opened it shows the updated table.

The purpose of this app is to shift from `MS-Excel` to an online app. Moreover, I am open to both local storage and remote storage approaches.

**Update** Based on Limey's excellent comment:

- Yes, all users/team members will see the same/current updates in the dataframe. By that I mean, if a user enters a new project number `33336` with its details and saves it, then the entire team including the manager will be able to see this new project added.
- Yes, multiple users might be using the app at the same time. Some might have opened it just to view it. Some team members might be adding their respective projects in the app at the same time. So, I don't really know how to resolve state conflicts.

How can I do this?

Sample Data (df):

```
structure(list(Reference.Number = c("33331", "33332", "33333", 
"33334", "33335"), Request.Date = c("1/6/2022", "1/6/2022", "1/19/2022", 
"1/20/2021", "1/24/2022"), Requestor.Name = c("Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", 
"Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", "Updated maps for David", 
"    Stone Cold", "Updated SOE 60 inch wall map"), Requestor.Dept.Div = c("C 3 Staff", 
"C 3 Staff", "Unincorp & Comm", "Mt.Rushmore AME Church Ft. Billy", 
"SOE"), Requestor.Phone = c("", "", "", "", ""), Contact.Person = c("Tommy", 
"Tommy", "Bob", "Bob", "Joe"), Contact.Phone = c("1111", 
"2222", "3333", "ext 1111", "3434"), Deadline = c("1/20/2022", 
"1/20/2022", "1/22/2022", "", "1/24/2022"), Project.Description = c("45x36 portrait map ", 
"45x36 portrait map  ", 
"24x24 Unincorporated areas, "Percent Females Aged 25 - 55  Below Poverty Level By Zip Code", 
"SOE Wall Map 60x60 p), Project.File.Location = c("", 
"", "C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14785 Unincorporated 24x24.pdf", 
"C:\\ABC\\Demographics\\Demographic_Request\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel.aprx", 
"C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14786 V P 60x60.pdf"
), PDF.File.....Map.Name.... = c("", "", "", "C:\\ABC\\Demographics\\Demographic_Request\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel\\pdfs\\MapNo14785.pdf", 
""), Assigned.To = c("", "", "", "", ""), Completion.Date = c("", 
"", "", "", ""), Notes = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Year = c(2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

    # Define UI for application 
    ui =   navbarPage(
                      tags$style("table, .table {color: unset;} .dataTable th, .datatables input {color: white}"),
                      title = div("GIS Team Projects"),
                      theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
                      tabPanel("GIS Projects",
                               icon = icon("info"),
                               div(p(h1("Instructions:"),style="text-align: justify;")),
                               p("1. The user can add their project details.", style="color:black"),
                               uiOutput("all"),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          actionButton("addData", "Add Project Details"),
                          actionButton("Save", "Please click here to save changes")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          downloadButton("download1","Download data as csv"),                
                          DTOutput("contents")),)
                        )
    )
    
    # Define server logic 
    server <- function(input, output) {
    
      myData = df
      
      # Create an 'empty' tibble 
       user_table =
         myData %>% 
          slice(1) %>% 
        # Transpose the first row of test into two columns
        gather(key = "column_name", value = "value") %>%
        # Replace all values with ""
        mutate(value = "") %>%
        # Reshape the data from long to wide
        spread(column_name, value) %>%
        # Rearrange the column order to match that of test
        select(colnames(myData))
       
       # Display data as is
       output$contents =
         renderDT(myData,
                  server = FALSE,
                  editable = TRUE,
                  options = list(lengthChange = TRUE),
                  rownames = FALSE)
       
       # Store a proxy of contents 
       proxy = dataTableProxy(outputId = "contents")
       
       # Each time addData is pressed, add user_table to proxy
       observeEvent(eventExpr = input$addData, {
         proxy %>% 
           addRow(user_table)
       })
      
    }
    
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think you're asking about persistent (server-side) data storage. RStudio has a great summary of options [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html). Have you seen this? We've used SQL db's for persistent storage in some of our shiny apps.

Comment: Plus one for @MauritsEvers' comment.  You also need to define what "the next time the app is opened" means:  by the same user? by any user?  Should all users see the same updates or do they require their open personal "save state"?    What if user 2 opens the app whilst user 1 is still using it?  How will you resolve state conflicts?  Etc, etc, etc...

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715897/shiny-how-to-remember-user-input-after-click-on-refresh/72716172#72716172) related answer for a bookmarking and a localStorage approach. As @Limey mentioned you'll need to provide more details on the use case.

Comment: @ismirsehregal kindly see updated question based on Limey's excellent comment.

Comment: Concurrent usage and the potential for simultaneous updates means you will need a database solution.  For me, that means the scope of the problem is too wide for a single SO question.  You will need to research your institution's infrastructure, decide on an appropriate remote (from the app) data storage solution, delevop a front end to access the database and then implement an interface between the app and the db front end.